# Floating Action buttons are not hiding in parallax effect

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.groomefy.consumer.Trending.DetailedActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/curve_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/postdetail_curve"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/backicon" />

                    <com.groomefy.consumer.fontutils.OpenSansBold
                        android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="@string/fragment_blogs"
                        android:textColor="@color/title_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_more"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/more_btn_height"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/more_btn_height"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:scaleType="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/more" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#a6a6a6" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/like_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
    android:src="@drawable/like"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/curve_image"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center_vertical" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fav_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/add_to_stylebook"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/curve_image"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/share_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/share"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/curve_image"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center_vertical|right"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
```

> this is my xml I want to hide the floating action buttons when I scroll but they just stick at the top and are not hiding 
>   i tried to put in different manner and i also saw [this](https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample) example

please sugges me what i am doing wrong

Comment: put `app:layout_behavior="saulmm.myapplication.AvatarImageBehavior"` inside your `FloatingActionButton` tag in xml

Answer (score 1):

You are use `RecycleView` so hide `FloatingActionButton` in `RecycleView` scroll use this way.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy){
            if (dy > 0)
                fabAddNew.hide();
            else if (dy < 0)
                fabAddNew.show();
        }
    });
```

Where `dy` is `parallel`.

Comment: i think you did not understand my problem

Comment: i have three fab and i want all of them to be stick with @id/curve_image and  i have given the layout_anchor and anchor_gravity    and i want to hide the FAB in parallex mode .....when i am scrolling the screen first main_image should collapse after that FAB ..........but this is not happening currently .....fab got stick  at the top and do not collapse with main image .............i hope ...i could make you understand my problem